# Can I change the Console Window Size?

Tags: c++, console, window

I'm currently writing a C++ program, and I know you can change the text colour but I was also wondering if you can change the Console Window size, and if so, how?

(Not talking about a Win32 Application)

Comment: [First Google hit for "winapi change console window size"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Would any of these help? Perhaps [`SetConsoleWindowInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686125%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<windows.h> 
using namespace std; 

SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW); 

int main(){ cout<<"Hello World"; }
```

Or You should be using

```
SetConsoleScreenBufferSize
SetConsoleWindowInfo
```

[There's an example at](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/10731/) http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/10731/

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreicated!